# Probe interaction for lm model - Error Class

Tags: r, interaction

I am new to R and have been trying to get the simple slopes of a two-way interaction including a factor (2 levels) and a continuous variable. Trying the probe_interactions from the interactions package in R gives the following error about the class. Sim_slopes also gives the same error. I know how to do this on Stata/SPSS but I need to get it working on R.

Does anyone have any information to solve this issue?

Many thanks in advance for any help!

```
> model1 <- lm(y ~  dummy * cont, data = data_new)
> probe_interaction(model = model1, pred = cont, modx = dummy, data = data_new)
Error:
! `class` must be a character vector, not a list.
Backtrace:
  1. interactions::probe_interaction(...)
  3. interactions::sim_slopes(...)
  5. jtools:::summ.lm(...)
  6. jtools:::do_robust(model, robust, cluster, data, vcov)
  7. jtools::get_robust_se(...)
  8. jtools::stop_wrap(...)
 10. rlang (local) `<fn>`(class = <named list>)
```

> sim_slopes(

- model = model1,
- pred = cont,
- modx = dummy,
- data = data_new)
  Error:
  ! `class` must be a character vector, not a list.
  Backtrace:

1. interactions::sim_slopes(...)
2. jtools:::summ.lm(...)
3. jtools:::do_robust(model, robust, cluster, data, vcov)
4. jtools::get_robust_se(...)
5. jtools::stop_wrap(...)
6. rlang (local) `<fn>`(class = )

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [the `marginaleffects` package](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/) (disclaimer: I am the author). It can do this and much much more. The website includes a short Getting Started guide and thousands words of tutorials:

https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/

Here’s a very simple replicable example with an interaction between a binary variable and a continuous one:

```r
library(marginaleffects)

mod <- lm(mpg ~ am * hp, data = mtcars)

mfx <- marginaleffects(mod)
summary(mfx)
#>   Term   Effect Std. Error z value   Pr(>|z|)    2.5 %   97.5 %
#> 1   am  5.27675   1.098721   4.803 1.5660e-06  3.12330  7.43021
#> 2   hp -0.05897   0.008726  -6.759 1.3922e-11 -0.07608 -0.04187
#> 
#> Model type:  lm 
#> Prediction type:  response

plot_cap(mod, condition = c("hp", "am"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was able to reproduce this on my data. However, the marginaleffects does not provide conditional values when am=0 or am=1 exactly. Instead I used margins and got these values with the following command: margins_summary(y, at=list(dummy=1)) and margins_summary(y, at=list(dummy=0)). I wonder if this is possible with the marginal effects package. Also, I am looking for a way to do a floodlight analysis (i.e., to determine the Johnson Neyman intervals on the continuous variable where the dummy is significant). If you have any information, that would be great! if not, thanks anyways!

Comment: @selin yes, this is definitely possible. `marginaleffects` was conceived as a successor to (path breaking) `margins`; it can do basically everything `margins` does and more. See this link for a side-by-side comparisons of the two packages. This will show you how to replicate results: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/alternative_software.html#margins-and-prediction You may also want to look at the docs for the different plotting functions: `plot_cap()`, `plot_cme()`, and `plot_cco()`. https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/reference/index.html#plots